# URL is not getting intercepted using Spring Security in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration

have developed one spring integration project in which i have implemented spring security.Configurations are fine.When i am hitting the to the given URL (e.g.localhost:8080/test/api) to fetch the response,the spring-security should intercept the request and should authenticate using spring security.

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="never" >
<intercept-url pattern="/api/" access="ROLE_USER" />
<http-basic entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The above are the basic configurations for spring security.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the spring security filter chain is not fired, many times is because being not configured in web app context.

Did you remember to set the spring security filter chain in web.xml:

```
<!--  Spring security filter -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be various resons why this does not work. I suggest you to follow a step-by-step tutorial and see if you are missing anything:

Here is one that is very basic and concentrates on getting a simple spring security configuration up and running:

http://jtuts.com/2016/03/02/spring-security-login-form-integration-example-with-xml-configuration/